# Using Javascript in iframe to target main page

Tags: javascript, iframe

I was reading this question, but my script is still not working:
[Can javascript running inside an iframe affect the main page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951946/can-javascript-running-inside-an-iframe-affect-the-main-page)

I have my main page test.php

```
<div id="testfield">Some text here</div> 
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="" style="..."></iframe>
```

In the iframe page I have a button that should be removing what's inside a div on the main page.

```
<button onclick="goNow();">TEST ME</button>
```

And this is the Javascript part that is triggered when pressed the button:

```
function goNow() {
parent.getElementById('testfield').innerHTML = '';
}
```

This all works on one page with document.getElementById, but once I use the iframe and parent.getElementById it returns an error:

```
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementById'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parent` refers to the parent *window*. You then need to get that window's document to continue.

```
parent.document.getElementById('testfield').innerHTML = "";
```