# Modify the iframe width

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a website of a customer like the following code.

The admin of this site let me put my own JavaScript (myScript.js). How can I change from this point (DOM Operations ?) the given iframe width from 160px to 200px?

```
<div id="iframeDiv">
<iframe width="160px" scrolling="no" src=/test/placement_content.jsp">
    <html>
        <body>
        <script src="myScript.js">
        ...
        ..
        .
```

Comment: Any help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11807287/1169519)?

Comment: can you give the frame and id?

Comment: `top.document.getElementById('iframeID')`

Comment: unfortunately not. The CMS Admin does not allowed :(                 Is there a way to jump from id= "iframeDiv" ?

Comment: @HonCivelek Why don't you just follow the link in my comment above, there's all you need...

Comment: Hi Temu, did they also work with more as one iframe on the page ?

Comment: @HonCivelek It works in any `iframe` on the page, no matter how many `iframe`s there are.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951946/can-javascript-running-inside-an-iframe-affect-the-main-page) to learn about writing JavaScript code that can affect a parent document when your script is loaded in a document in an `iframe`.  Note this only works when both the parent document and child document are within the same domain.

You should be able to get the 'iFrameDiv' element on the parent, find the child that is your `iframe`, and manipulate the `width`