# Getting a response from an iframe

Tags: html, iframe, qualtrics

I want to move a game/puzzle from Website A (Bebras) onto a survey on Website B (Qualtrics). Qualtrics was being fussy about the embedded CSS and JS in the HTML code I copied from website A as there is no file hierarchy on Qualtrics. To have the puzzle display on Qualtrics, I used an iframe in my HTML code:

```
    <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="800" src="https://fi-
    engage.s3.amazonaws.com/CarTrip/roboWithoutSave.html" width="560">
    </iframe>
```

The issue is that I'm not sure how to get a response or return result from Website A/Bebras through the iframe so that I can determine whether someone answered the puzzle correctly. Is there a response attribute I can attach in the iframe tag? Or another way to do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The nature of iFrames is such that it isn't really possible to do what you are attempting. The only way for Qualtrics to talk to the js in the game is to do an integration of the game directly into Qualtrics instead of using an iFrame.

Comment: Well... that's not entirely true, but only assuming you have direct control over both elements. Even then, in my opinion it is better practice to not do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951946/can-javascript-running-inside-an-iframe-affect-the-main-page